# How to prevent overwriting context this in ES6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, this, jquery-events

Very similar to [How to prevent jquery to override "this"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053932/how-to-prevent-jquery-to-override-this) but in ES6.

This is my class:

```
class FeedbackForm {
  constructor(formEl) {
    this.$form = $(formEl)
    this.$form.submit(this.sendStuff)

    this.alerts = $('#something');
  }

  /**
   * Sends the feedback
   * @param {Event} e
   */
  sendStuff(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    if (this.alerts.length) {
      window.alert('Notice... stuff')
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: this.$form.prop('method'),
      url: this.$form.prop('action'),
      data: this.$form.serialize()
    }).done(() => window.location.reload(true))
  }
}
```

The `sendStuff` method is the event handler of the form, and jQuery calls it using [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) I believe. Therefore, `this` inside `sendStuff` is overwritten with the event target that jQuery applies and I can't access `this.alerts` or any other property methods.

I'm not sure if I can apply the `var that = this` trick here or how do I work around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function expression (also known as fat arrow function) has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions **and lexically binds the this value**

This should do it:

```
this.$form.submit(e => this.sendStuff(e));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can associate the `FeedbackForm` instance with the form element using a symbol.

Then, inside the event listener, `this` or `e.currentTarget`  will be the form element. Using the symbol you retrieve the `FeedbackForm` instance.

```js
const myFeedbackForm = Symbol();
class FeedbackForm {
  constructor(formEl) {
    formEl[myFeedbackForm] = this;
    this.$form = $(formEl);
    this.$form.submit(this.sendStuff);
    this.alerts = $('#something');
  }
  sendStuff(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (this[myFeedbackForm].alerts.length) {
      window.alert('Notice... stuff')
    }
  }
}
new FeedbackForm(document.forms[0]).$form.submit();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form></form>
<div id="something"></div>
```

The limitation is that you can't associate the same form element with different `FeedbackForm` instances.

Comment: This is an interesting method too but the arrow function worked and other developers here agreed that it was more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing a second sort of storage variable from outside of the scope of both functions inside the main one:

```
var that;
class FeedbackForm {

  constructor(formEl) {
    this.$form = $(formEl)
    this.alerts = $('#something');
    that = this;

    this.$form.submit(this.sendStuff)    
  }

  /**
   * Sends the feedback
   * @param {Event} e
   */
  sendStuff(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    if (that.alerts.length) {
      window.alert('Notice... stuff')
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: that.$form.prop('method'),
      url: that.$form.prop('action'),
      data: that.$form.serialize()
    }).done(() => window.location.reload(true))
  }
}
```

Comment: That crashed Babelify with a syntax error when I tried to transpile as I believe it isn't allowed: "A class body can only contain methods, but not data properties." http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html

Comment: I have edited my answer. Outside of the class perhaps? Sorry, I guess I am shooting in the dark here.